# sort array properties with php preg_replace

Tags: php, arrays, string, function, preg-replace

Pretty much self explanatory what I'm trying to achieve here...

I thing that the function is getting $1 instead of the real actual string.

a tiny small tweak can make it work :)

Why it's not working ?

```
<?php

function mySort($arr) {
    sort($arr);
    return $arr;
}

$css = <<<EOF

body {
z-index : 9;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
line-height: 10px;
}

p {
z-index: 9;
font-size: 10px;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
z-index: 2;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-size: 100%;
border: 0 none;
}

EOF;

echo '<pre>'.preg_replace( '~.*?{(.*?)}~s', implode ( ";", mySort( explode( ";" , "$1" ) ) ) , $css ).'</pre>';
```

Comment: It is not self-explanatory what you are trying to do.

Comment: OK I WILL EDIT MY QUESTION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `preg_replace_callback`:

```
echo '<pre>'.preg_replace_callback( '~.*?{(.*?)}~s',
    function ($match) use ($css) {
        return implode ( ";", mySort( explode( ";" , $match[1] ) ) );
    },
$css ).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in :

return implode ( ";", mySort( explode( ";" , $match[1] ) ) ) , $css );

Comment: Warning: preg_replace_callback() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given in C:\server\htdocs\index.php on line 36

Comment: My mistake.  Sorry.  `$css` is actually the third argument...  I fixed it in the question.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

The third argument needs to be a string:

```
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Also...
It is not clear in yuor code what `"$1"` represents? Is this a string? the tring you want to replace? Or is it a php variable? `$1`

It looks as thou you are trying to pass the CSSS to `mySort()`? 
IS that correct?

Comment: `$1` is used in regex to represent the group 1 match.